# Subscribing to MvxMessage from Android Client

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Using Xamarin and MvvmCross, where in an Android Client View do I subscribe to messages from the Core project, I tried this code which doesn't get executed:

```
 public HomeView(IMvxMessenger messenger)
 {
     _messenger = messenger;

     // Subscribe to inter-app message "ApplicationError_Message"
     _messageToken = messenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<ApplicationError_Message>(Display_Error);
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't really follow your example code - it didn't really explain:

- how you were creating your HomeView
- how it was getting its messenger instance passed to it.
- what was generating the ApplicationError_Message messages
- how you were understanding whether or not the message was or wasn't arriving

As a quick test I modified the Android HomeView in the InternetMinute sample - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/InternetMinute

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Cirrious.CrossCore;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger;
using InternetMinute.Core;

namespace InternetMinute.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity(Label = "Internet time is ticking")]
    public class HomeView : MvxActivity
    {
        private MvxSubscriptionToken _token;

        private IMvxMessenger _messenger;
        protected IMvxMessenger Messenger
        {
            get 
            { 
                _messenger = _messenger ?? Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
                return _messenger;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomeView);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            _token = Messenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<TickMessage>(OnTick);
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            Messenger.Unsubscribe<TickMessage>(_token);
            _token = null;
            base.OnPause();
        }

        private int _i = 0;
        private void OnTick(TickMessage obj)
        {
            Mvx.Trace("Tick received {0}", ++_i);
        }
    }
}
```

That seemed to work fine - I got the trace I was expecting.

Perhaps your SubscribeOnMainThread isn't subscribing for the correct message type - what type is the compiler inferring?

Comment: That works - as far as my code goes, I was expecting the framework to inject the messenger in the constructor but as I can tell from your example it doesn't do that and you need to use Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>() on the property and then subscribe to the messages in the OnResume and unsubscribe in the OnPause. Thanks!

Comment: So what were you seeing - a null reference exception? Or were you providing multiple constructors? The more info you can provide in questions, the better I'll try to target my answers - thanks :)

As for OnPause/OnResume, that's only what my example did - what works for your app depends on what the lifecycles are for your app, your activity and for your messages - it's up to you to code :)

Comment: I had no clue where to subscribe to the messager so I followed the same approach as used in the .Core PCL - i.e. I created a constructor with an IMvxMessenger typed parameter and expected it to be injected by MvvmCross. After debugging, I found that the constructor was never fired so I then knew that MvvmCross didn't work that way in the Droid app. I just needed to know the correct approach to getting hold of the MvxMessenger which you answered. I guess I needed an N+x tutorial or some sample - which you provided with the GitHub link - thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just as a little background - I have only been working on my project for the past two weeks and have had to pick up MvvmCross quickly. I haven't been keeping up with it since your first version. I only have a few days before I start a new job so I am rushing to get this finished before my last day. Thanks for all the help, I have now got a toast popping up in the emulator :)

Comment: still not sure how your class got constructed if the constructor wasn't called... but no matter... fwiw, the reason we don't do constructor injection for the views is because Android itself creates them - Android responds to `Intent`s and creates the `MvxActivity`/`View` - the first chance Mvx gets to do anything is when the `OnCreate` gets called. (A similar story is also true in WP and WinRT too).

Comment: Oh, If I have a constructor with no arguments, that gets called. When I added one with the messenger parameter, it didn't get called this is because of what you just said - you don't call it. BTW, this is the View I am taking about so what you just said makes sense.